# TensorFlow-Slim Multi-GPU training

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, multi-gpu, tf-slim

I'm using TensorFlow-Slim. My aim is to run a given standard script (located in /models/slim/scripts) in multi-GPU mode. I've tested the finetune_resnet_v1_50_on_flowers.sh script (cloned on 12.04.2017). I've just added --num_clones=2 at the end of the training part (inspired by /slim/deployment/model_deploy_test.py and previous StackOverflow answers):

```
python train_image_classifier.py \
  --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --dataset_name=flowers \
  --dataset_split_name=train \
  --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
  --model_name=resnet_v1_50 \
  --checkpoint_path=${PRETRAINED_CHECKPOINT_DIR}/resnet_v1_50.ckpt \
  --checkpoint_exclude_scopes=resnet_v1_50/logits \
  --trainable_scopes=resnet_v1_50/logits \
  --max_number_of_steps=3000 \
  --batch_size=32 \
  --learning_rate=0.01 \
  --save_interval_secs=60 \
  --save_summaries_secs=60 \
  --log_every_n_steps=100 \
  --optimizer=rmsprop \
  --weight_decay=0.00004 \
  --num_clones=2
```

Code from deployment/model_deploy_test.py:

```
def testMultiGPU(self):
    deploy_config = model_deploy.DeploymentConfig(num_clones=2)
```

I've got one warning ('Ignoring device specification'):

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:86:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:669] Ignoring device specification /GPU:1 for node 'clone_1/fifo_queue_Dequeue' because the input edge from 'prefetch_queue/fifo_queue' is a reference connection and already has a device field set to /CPU:0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:669] Ignoring device specification /GPU:0 for node 'clone_0/fifo_queue_Dequeue' because the input edge from 'prefetch_queue/fifo_queue' is a reference connection and already has a device field set to /CPU:0
```

The GPUs run normally (memory usage and GPU utilization), but the training is not faster compared with a single GPU training.

This issue might be related to: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8061

I would be very pleased to receive your answers, opinions or concrete proposals to this problem.

CUDA version: release 8.0, V8.0.53

TensorFlow installed from binary, tested versions: 1.0.1 and 1.1.0rc

GPU: NVIDIA Tesla P100 (SXM2)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this document
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12689
To make sure that the Variables are stored in CPU, we need to use context manager
with `slim.arg_scope([slim.model_variable, slim.variable], device='/cpu:0'):`

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

even if this answer might be late, the training is not supposed to be faster ( measured in seconds per steps). There is another model created instead, leading to an effective batch size of 64 with your parameters, so you can half your maximal number of steps.

Comment: is using two gpu with batch size 32 same as single gpu with batch size 64?

Comment: No, because you will need to adapt the learning rate and the learning rate decay. You will also need to adapt the number of epochs per decay.

Comment: I mean if we only consider the batch size.  I also find out that, with multi gpus, it is getting slower. Before that, I thought bath size will be divided by the number of the gpus, and it is getting faster. As far as I understanding your comment, it is multiplying the number of the batch size. Am I correct?